# signTransaction removes partialSigned signatures making it impossible to sign a partial signed transaction using wallet adaptor

Tags: transaction, sign

### Problem

1. Create instruction in backend server and partial sign it with a private key
2. Serialize the transaction and send it to the Frontend
3. Frontend deserialize transaction, and signs with the wallet adaptor
4. Frontend sends and confirms transaction

### This is where the problem occurs

signTransaction using the wallet adaptor removes the partialSigned. This is a problem because wallet adaptors can't partial sign, they can only sign, which removes any partial sign done in a backend server.

I had to do the opposite, sign using the wallet adapter, then serialize the transaction send it over to the backend, and then the backend partial signs using a private key and sends the transaction

I can't do it the other way around, ie. i always have to end with partial sign and not sign. But wallet adaptors are not able to partial sign, only sign - which removes any partial signed (from my backend)

Am am I getting something wrong? Or is this intended or a bug?

Comment: Are you using a legacy transaction (`Transaction`) or a VersionedTransaction (`VersionedTransaction`)? Reason I ask is because the answer to addressing is different based on this.

Comment: Hi @Ahri I was using Transaction, i was reading the VersionedTransaction and see its a little different (does not replace the signatures) am currently trying to see if that works

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For completeness, this is a common issue when using the `Transaction` class in web3js. It has 2 sign methods, `sign` and `partialSign`

If you call `sign` then it resets the signatures, field, ie removes any previous signers: https://github.com/solana-labs/solana-web3.js/blob/35de86bcc20a751ec4d30bbe0788b402b43f2eb9/packages/library-legacy/src/transaction/legacy.ts#L679-L682

If you call `partialSign` then it only adds new signatures and doesn't affect existing ones: https://github.com/solana-labs/solana-web3.js/blob/35de86bcc20a751ec4d30bbe0788b402b43f2eb9/packages/library-legacy/src/transaction/legacy.ts#L724-L727

This means that if you get a transaction from an API that has already been signed, you need to use `partialSign` to add your signature.

Most wallet adapters use `partialSign`, and wallet-adapter uses it in other places where it adds signers. This is mostly a legacy concern because most wallets now use `wallet-standard` which doesn't depend on these web3js types. But it does affect code that still uses the `Transaction` object from web3js.

This was fixed for `VersionedTransaction` which only has a `sign` method, which doesn't reset signatures: https://github.com/solana-labs/solana-web3.js/blob/35de86bcc20a751ec4d30bbe0788b402b43f2eb9/packages/library-legacy/src/transaction/versioned.ts#L107

Comment: Thanks for the explanation!

Answer (score 2):

I was doing your described flow in this example program:
https://github.com/solana-developers/one-milion-nfts

So in the backend you partialy sign the transactions with the flags:

```
verifySignatures: false,
requireAllSignatures: false,
```

Looking like this:

```
const transaction = await mintCompressedNft(
    CONNECTION,
    nftArgs,
    ownerWallet.publicKey,
    TreeAccount,
    CollectionMint,
    collectionMetadataAccount, 
    collectionMasterEditionAccount,
    feepayer
  );
  transaction.recentBlockhash = hash.blockhash;

  transaction.partialSign(ownerWallet);
  console.log("transaction " + transaction.instructions.length);
  
  const serializedTransaction = transaction.serialize({
    verifySignatures: false,
    requireAllSignatures: false,
  });

  const base64Transaction = serializedTransaction.toString('base64');

  res.status(200).json({
    transaction: base64Transaction,
    message: "OK",
  });
```

In the client you can then sign the transaction using the wallet adapter and send it like so:

```
const jsonResponse = await response.json(); //extract JSON from the http response

const decodedTx = Buffer.from(jsonResponse.transaction, "base64");
const transaction = Transaction.from(decodedTx);

const signature = await sendTransaction(transaction, CONNECTION, {
  skipPreflight: true,
});
```

Comment: Hey Jonas thanks for the reply, yea that was my flow as well. Only difference was i was not using wallet sendTransaction as was not using react. I was looking at the code from sendTransaction, apparently it uses partialSign if there is > 0 signers. partialSign requires a keypair as input though which is not available to FE wallet adaptor

https://github.com/solana-labs/wallet-adapter/blob/0a1c89938698dbff8091e98ca0eb01b5fcca33cd/packages/core/base/src/signer.ts#L27

Line 67:                    signers?.length && transaction.partialSign(...signers);

Comment: Hmm my bad actually sendTransaction it only does partialSign if additional signers are passed in the options. Let me try with VersionedTransaction instead

Answer (score 1):

Ahh silly me, i had a bug that was using the wrong wallet address, Verified that it works for both Transaction (partial sign on backend -> sign on frontend) and VersionTransaction (sign on backend -> sign on backend)

Thanks and will close it.

For others who might be interested, this was the use case. I was trying to pay for the account creation. There is 2 signers, the payer is the fee payer and the signer is the actual owner

```
#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct CreateUser<'info> {
    #[account(
        init_if_needed,
        payer = payer, // the payer might not be the signer (pay on behalf of the signer)
        seeds = [b"user", signer.key().as_ref()],
        bump,
        space = User::len(),
    )]
    pub user: Account<'info, User>,
    #[account(mut)]
    pub payer: Signer<'info>,
    pub signer: Signer<'info>,
    pub system_program: Program<'info, System>,
}
```

Then creating the instruction here

```
async createUserIx({
        geohash,
        region,
        wallet,
        payer,
    }: {
        geohash: number[];
        region: number[];
        wallet?: PublicKey | null;
        payer?: PublicKey | null;
    }): Promise<TransactionInstruction> {
        const [pda, _] = this.getUserPda(wallet);

        return await this.program.methods
            .createUser(region, geohash)
            .accounts({
                user: pda,
                signer: wallet,
                payer: payer,
                systemProgram: SystemProgram.programId,
            })
            .instruction();
    }
```

After than sign -> serializing -> deserialize -> sign -> send works